# Finding Fourier series of $\sin^2 x$ (STILL not clear - read comments)

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

I am attempting to do some sums on Fourier series, but need help with one calculation, after which I can proceed on my own.

The question is:

1. Find the Fourier series for f(x) = $\sin^2x$, on $[-\pi,\pi]$.

I can find $a_0$ by doing the following:

$$ a_0=\frac 1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^2xdx$$ It works out to be $1/2$.

*Important:* Is this method of finding $a_0$ correct?

*Main question*: How can I find $a_n$ (coefficients of cosine terms in the fourier series) for this function? I assume $b_n$ (coefficients of sine terms) does not exist, since this is an even function. I know that $a_n$ will only have a non-zero value for $n=2$, but **can someone please show this with full working (all steps)**. Then I can proceed on my own with the other sums.

I would like to see how the fourier series leads to the answer $\frac 12 - \frac 12\cos(2x)$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Let's try and find $a_n$. You know what the values of integrals like $\cos (nx)\cos (mx)$ are. Now, if only we could describe $\sin^2 x$ as a function of $\cos$'s we could solve the problem. Now use:
$$\sin^2 x = 1 - \cos^2 x = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(2 x)-1)$$ 
And then you can easily see that other than the constant term ($n=0$), only the $n=2$ term is non-zero.

Comment: Can you explain in further detail? I am not understanding what you mean exactly, please. How is it seen that only $a_n$ for n=2 is non-zero?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could please show your entire working. I am new to this concept, and it is quite tough.

Comment: @user119183 - sorry, I forgot the most important part. Is it clearer now?

Comment: A small remark: not only the $n=2$ term but also the $n=0$ term is nonzero.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro - thanks :)

Comment: I am still getting confused... If you multiply cos(nx) by cos(mx), you get (1/2)((cos(n+m)+(n-m)). But the integral of cos(nx)cos(mx) over $-\pi$ to $\pi$ is zero. So how does this help?

Comment: Please watch parentheses when using slashes for division.  In $1/2(\cos(2x)-1)$ it is not clear whether the final term is in the numerator or denominator.  In this case, it should be in the numerator, but we see this expression frequently where it should be in the denominator.

Comment: @nbubis, I kindly request you to post another answer, with $a_n$ fully solved for, and shown for n=2, why it's non-zero. It would be extremely helpful of you, I'd be grateful for it.

Comment: @user119183 He's just using a trig identity on $\sin^2 x$ which happens to give him a Fourier series.

Comment: I understood that; I know that we can directly use the identity of $sin^2x = \frac 12 + \frac 12cos(2x)$ to find it. However, it's necessary that I understand the fully solved method, using integrals to solve for $a_n$. Could you shed light on this please?

Comment: @user119183 - I am using integrals, in a sense. Plug in the expression into the integral, and note that $\int \cos(nx)\cos (mx) = 0$ for $n\neq m$, and $1$ for $m=n$.

Comment: Ahh, let me check that and get back to you within 15 minutes. Thanks!

Comment: SO, what you're saying is, that regardless of the limits, the integral of $cos(mx)cos(nx)$ will always be equal to 1? But how do the limits come into consideration then? Do you integrate specially for the case n=2?

Comment: @user119183 - no. In your case the integral is $\pi$.

Comment: Wait... I am getting confused. I am integrating from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, right? What do you mean my integral is $\pi$? Those are my limits... And, by the way, thanks for you repeated help.

Comment: The integral from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ is $\pi$.

Comment: Oh my god. That was amazingly obvious, yet I did not recognize it. Thank you so much, my good friend. You are the most helpful person ever. $\pi$ * 1 = $\pi$... thanks!

Comment: I accepted yours, can't upvote yet. But thank you.